# Zend framework 2 Soap Server doesnt return response

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework, wsdl, soapserver

I am trying to create a soap server with zend but when i try to make a request with Postman, I always receive 'Could not get any response'. In non-wsdl mode it works fine.

Please help!

```
public function wsAction()
{
    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
        header ("Content-Type: application/xml");
        $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover();
        $autodiscover->setClass('Order\Service\OrderService')
                     ->setUri('http://example.gr/public/order/ws')
                     ->setServiceName('OrderService');
        echo $autodiscover->toXml();
        return $this->getResponse();
    }
    else
    {
        $server = new Server('http://example.gr/public/order/ws?wsdl',array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,'trace'=>1));
        $server->setClass('Order\Service\OrderService');
        $server->handle();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you are missing a "return"-statement in the else branch...